# Pop!_OS GNOME shell keeps freezing

Tags: gnome, pop-os

The shell keeps randomly freezing, and I'm unable to click anything (such as the dock or application windows).

Sometimes I manage to restart the shell with `Alt + F2` and entering `r`, or with `killall -3 gnome-shell`. But then soon after the same problem occurs.

This is a fresh OS install I've been using for about 3 weeks now. This problem only started happening recently. I'm not sure what's caused it or how to go about fixing it, since there is no error popup when this happens.

This is a huge pain and my OS has become almost unusable, which is ridiculous since I only just did a fresh install.

I suspect it may have started after a recent update to the OS. But other than that, I have no idea what's causing it.

If I knew this OS was going to be this unstable, I would've just used Ubuntu.

I opened a GitHub issue regarding this, because it seems to be a hardware-related bug with this OS: https://github.com/pop-os/pop/issues/1960

I've never had it happen in Ubuntu, which I was running for a long time (including with the Pop!_OS shell GNOME plugin for over a year).

I suspect it may be a hardware failure. I was getting the same sort of freezing, even when running Ubuntu on a USB. Might just need to get a new PC, mine is very old and dying. I replaced the SSD a month ago but that didn't work.

### Environment

- Pop!_OS 21.04
- GNOME 3.38.5

Comment: Alt+F2 to restart, seems running Xorg backend. Have you tried starting Gnome-shell with Wayland? If POP is like Ubuntu, you may change the Desktop Backend in the logging screen.

Comment: @user.dz I'm giving Wayland a shot, I'll let you know how it goes

Comment: @user.dz same issue with Wayland.

Comment: any gnome-shell-extensions active?

Comment: When shell freezes are you able to switch tty? if so track the PID and take a look at ```lsof -p PID``` and/or ```strace -p PID``` to see what the processes is doing and where is getting hung up

Comment: @nobody nope just what came installed

Comment: @HeysusEscobar the PID for what process?

Comment: the PID for the process that is freezing. Also, have you taken a look at the logs? When the issue is happening switch ttyand look at journalctl for any error

Comment: @HeysusEscobar there's no particular that's freezing. It's the entire shell and all applications. Check my edit, I think this is probably a hardware issue (not software).